# fail to combine string VBA Excel after I Split that string

Tags: excel, vba

I try to skip one word from a string after that i want to combine string that already split into one, using "for" looping but, when I want to combine again the split word i can't get result that i want.

Here is My Code:

```
Function FindData(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim Text As String, SplitText() As String
Dim j As Integer, CountText As Integer

SplitText = Split(lookup_value)
CountText = UBound(SplitText()) + 1

For j = 1 To CountText
Text = Text & SplitText(j) & " "
Next j

FindData = Text
End Function
```

The Input is:

```
=FindData(A2,C2)
```

Where Value A2 = "Aku Kamu Dia"
C2 skip cause c2 still not use here

My Hope Result:

```
Kamu Dia
```

But I get :

```
#VALUE!
```

Someone Plis help me

Comment: You set `CountText  = UBound(SplitText()) + 1`, that means the  For-Loop exceeds the upper boundary of the splitText-Array. That causes a runtime error 9. If you use the formula as UDF, Excel will show `#VALUE!` as result of that function.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying but `CountText = UBound(SplitText()) + 1` looks problematic anyway. How can you expect a loop to work when you manually adjust the range here? Can you explain exactly what it is you want to achieve? Trim of the 1st word?

Comment: Thanks for the time sir @FunThomas and JvdV. Mr Harun already show me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed ***delimiter*** argument of `Split()` function. From your expected result, it seems you are trying skip first word. So, try to concatenate from 2nd element of array. Start loop from `1` as array position always start from `0` zero.

```
Function FindData(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim Text As String, SplitText() As String
Dim j As Integer, CountText As Integer

SplitText = Split(lookup_value, " ")

    For j = 1 To UBound(SplitText)
        Text = Text & SplitText(j) & " "
    Next j

FindData = Text
End Function
```

Comment: If the delimiter argument of `Split` is omitted, it uses the default which is the space character, so that was not the problem.

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks for information. I thought it was required argumrnt.